# Viewport material shading looks like face orientation is wrong but the issue is something else

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, 3d-view, normals

The next image will show the problem I am having.

[image: Material View]

I've been playing around trying to fix this, I had this issue ages ago once but I never found a fix, a year later it has cropped up again. I have checked face orientation, normals are facing the correct way, there are no extra faces inbetween those sections, I have merged vertices by distance, applied rotation and scale, my seams and UV seem alright and I have no marked sharp edges. Images shown below, what have i missed?

[image]

Above is the blend file.

[image: face orientation]

[image: Merge by distance]

[image: Normals and no extra faces]

[image: Rotation and Scale]

[image: Seams]

[image: UV Layout]

[image: After trying suggested fixes]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it looks like it may be a Blend Mode issue. Try changing Blend Modes in the Material Properties tab. I can't tell if you're using transparency or not, but if not, make sure it's set to _opaque_.

Comment: @moonboots I believe I have now uploaded the blend file now, I have removed all other content apart from the issue asset

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I am actually using Alpha blend in order to get the transparency of the leaf. Unfortunately that did not fix it, I changed it to opaque blend mode.

Comment: you need to copy the link it gives you and paste it here

Comment: The alpha-blend may be the cause. Try alpha-hashed, or check your transparency arrangement to make sure you're not culling the front faces.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=DySKdvzg" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DySKdvzg/)

apologies here is the link @moonboots

Comment: Neither of the blend modes seem to be affecting it, I just tried Alpha Hashed and checked backfaced culling as you suggested but this unfortunately did not fix it

Comment: Try changing the color space of the image texture you're using for your alpha from sRGB to non-color

Comment: So what I did was actually change the blend mode to Alpha Hashed and then change the alpha channel texture node to Non Colour and that has fixed it. Your an absolute genius my friend, thanks for the help! You can put that into an answer and ill happily up vote it and comment :)

Comment: In the material, disable the Show Backface option?

Comment: It also actually seems to work with Alpha Blend as well, but this was only once I changed all the materials alpha textures to non colour I believe, though I'm not sure why this would be.

Comment: @moonboots I believe this could work but in this instance since I am creating foliage It needs it to be double sided, disabling backface culling shows the texture only on one side

Comment: I'm  not talking about Backface Culling but Show Backface, it seems like it is just affecting the Material Preview (unless you're in Eevee)

Comment: Oh I seeee, I'm with you the option just below it. Hmm do you know why this is?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: So my answer fixed the problem on my computer but not on yours apparently...

*Show Backface* seems to be the option you want to disable, it will affect the *Material Preview* in Cycles, it won't affect the *Render*, except in Eevee:

[image]

Comment: file:///I:/004%20Personal%20Work/StackExchange/Sading/InkedStill%20not%20working_LI.jpg So it still seems to be having issues. I have managed to fix it on my main file but that was through various different ways, including changed it to Alpha Hashed and Non colour in the alpha material. I think your way does fix it but not always maybe? I'm not sure

Comment: I can't see the link   ;)

Comment: Whoops :P can I edit it into your answer? im not very good at this am i haha EDIT* I added it to mine

Comment: you can edit your question, weird that it doesn't fix the problem though, it works fine here

Comment: Yup just did cheers, its the final image. Very odd indeed, like I mentioned it did seem to get fixed but the fix seems random in a way

Answer (score 1):

So I found the Solution with the help of @moonboots and @ChristopherBennet, here are the images explaining.

1. If using an Alpha Blend or Alpha Hashed mode with an alpha texture node, make sure Non Colour is selected in the colour space drop down.

[image: Shader settings]

2. Disable "Show Backface" under the "Materials tab", "Viewport Display."

[image: Disable Show Backface]

3. Get rid of any extra materials or make sure they follow the same settings, if using multiple objects, separate objects and texture separately.

[image: Extra materials]

Comment: @moonboots So I think because these materials were attached to it and they had the BackFace enabled and Colour Space set to sRGB they were conflicting with the main material. I was able to re-repeat these steps and consistently fix the problem